# the angle between $Ax$ and $x = [0, 1]^T$ is

Tags: linear-algebra

If the trace and the determinant of an orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrix A are 1, then
the angle between $Ax$ and $x = [0, 1]^T$ is

(i) $25^{\circ}$

(ii) $30^{\circ}$

(iii) $45^{\circ}$

(iv) $60^{\circ}$

I just see the characteristic polynomial is $x^2-x+1=0$, could any one tell me how to solve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix is either a reflection or a rotation.

The determinant is $+1$, so it is a rotation.

A $2\times 2$ rotation matrix has the form
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array} \right).$$

The trace is also $+1$, i.e. $2\cos\theta = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the matrix is orthogonal and its determinant is 1, we know that 
$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array} \right).$$ for some $\theta$. We also know that $2\cos{\theta}=1$ by taking the trace, hence $\theta=60^o$. So $Ax=[-\sin{60^o},1/2]^T,$ hence $Ax\cdot x=\frac{1}{2}=cos{\phi}$ where $\phi$ is the angle between $Ax$ and $x$, hence the angle is $60^o$.

Comment: In the above argument, I do not understand the line "So $Ax=[1/2,\sin{60^o}]^T,$" As I see that $$ Ax=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array} \right) \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin \theta\\ 
\cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin 60 ^{\circ}\\ 
\frac 12
\end{pmatrix}$$ at $\theta =60^{\circ}$. Can someone plz. explain where I went wrong?

Comment: @learner that may be right.

Comment: @JLA If I am right ,can you plz. modify the answer?